Ignore some differences in Redgate SQL Compare
I use SQL Compare for comparing my databases. I have a problem in comparing where in another database, the create procedure is like this:
Create   procedure

and I want to ignore diffs like this.

Is it possible to ignore this changes?
I mean ignore "proc" and "procedure" changes...

The command-line option /exclude:<type>:<regular expression> seems to do that?: https://documentation.red-gate.com/sc/using-the-command-line/switches-used-in-the-command-line#:~:text=/-,exclude%3A%3Ctype%3E%3A%3Cregular%20expression%3E,-Excludes%20objects%20from
